# Extension of Borel-Cantelli in Probability Theory

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, measure-theory, borel-cantelli-lemmas

I am working on a problem regarding an extension of the Borel-Cantelli lemma that goes as follows:

Let $E_1, E_2, ...$ be an arbitrary sequence of sets. It is known that $\lim_{n \to \infty}P(E_n) = 0$ and $\sum_n P(E_n \cap E_{n+1}^c) < \infty$. Show that $P(E_n \text{ infinitely often})=0$

I have tried a few different attempts at the answer, with the most current one given below:

\begin{align*}
      &P(\limsup_n E_n)&&\\
      &= P(\cap_{n=1}^\infty \cup_{k=n}^\infty E_n)&&\\
      &= \lim_{n \nearrow \infty} P(\cup_{k=n}^\infty E_n)&&\text{intersection is monotone decreasing}\\
      &= \lim_{n \nearrow \infty} P\bigg(\cup_{k=n}^\infty \big[[E_n \cap E_{n+1}^c] \cup [E_n \cap E_{n+1}]\big]\bigg)&&\\
      &= \lim_{n \nearrow \infty} P\bigg(\big(\cup_{k=n}^\infty [E_n \cap E_{n+1}^c]\big) \cup \big(\cup_{k=n}^\infty [E_n \cap E_{n+1}]\big)\bigg)&&\\
      &= \lim_{n \nearrow \infty} P\bigg(\big(\cup_{k=n}^\infty [E_n \cap E_{n+1}^c]\big) \cup \big(\cup_{k=n}^\infty E_n \cap \cup_{k=n}^\infty E_{n+1}]\big)\bigg)&&\\
      &= \lim_{n \nearrow \infty} P\bigg(\big(\cup_{k=n}^\infty [E_n \cap E_{n+1}^c]\big) \cup [\cup_{k=n}^\infty E_{n+1}]\bigg)&&\\
      &= \lim_{n \nearrow \infty} \bigg[P\big(\cup_{k=n}^\infty [E_n \cap E_{n+1}^c]\big)+ P\big(\cup_{k=n}^\infty E_{n+1}\big)\bigg]&&\text{disjoint additivity}\\
      &= \lim_{n \nearrow \infty} P\big(\cup_{k=n}^\infty [E_n \cap E_{n+1}^c]\big)+ \lim_{n \nearrow \infty} P\big(\cup_{k=n}^\infty E_{n+1}\big)&&\\
      &\leq \lim_{n \nearrow \infty} \sum_{k=n}^\infty P\big(E_n \cap E_{n+1}^c\big)+ \lim_{n \nearrow \infty} P\big(\cup_{k=n}^\infty E_{n+1}\big)&&\text{subadditivity}\\
    \end{align*}

The main problem with this answer, as well as the other ones I have drafted, is that I can't seem to get rid of the union over $E_n$. Because of this I can't make any statements about the limiting probability of the union going to $0$ (e.g. if $P(E_n) = 1/n$ the conditions of the problem are fulfilled but the probability of the union does not converge).

Am I missing something in the way I am breaking up the sets? I have been banging my head against this for days with no success - any resources you all could suggest/ direction that you could give would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that there is no typo in the statement of your problem? See this related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/220686/36150

Comment: There is no typo - but perhaps the same approach would be useful. Do you understand why the first line of the related proof is true? I don't understand why the inequality in Davide's reply holds...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**

1. Show that for any $\omega \in \bigcup_{n \geq k} E_n$ one of the following conditions is satisfied:

   a) there exists $N \geq k$ such that $\omega \in E_n$ for all $n \geq N$,

   b) there exists $n \geq k$ such that $\omega \in E_{n}$ and $\omega \notin E_{n+1}$.

   This gives $$\bigcup_{n \geq k} E_n \subseteq \left( \bigcup_{N \geq k} \bigcap_{n \geq N} E_n \right) \cup \bigcup_{n \geq k} (E_n \cap E_{n+1}^c).$$
2. It follows from Step 1 that $$\mathbb{P} \left( \bigcup_{n \geq k} E_n \right) \leq \mathbb{P} \left( \bigcup_{N \geq k} \bigcap_{n \geq N} E_n \right) + \sum_{n \geq k} \mathbb{P}(E_n \cap E_{n+1}^c).$$
3. Since $\bigcap_{n \geq N} E_n$ is increasing in $N$, it holds that $$\mathbb{P} \left( \bigcup_{N \geq k} \bigcap_{n \geq N} E_n \right)  = \lim_{N \to \infty} \mathbb{P} \left( \bigcap_{n \geq N} E_n \right)$$ and so $$\mathbb{P} \left( \bigcup_{N \geq k} \bigcap_{n \geq N} E_n \right) \leq \lim_{N \to \infty} \mathbb{P}(E_N)=0.$$
4. Combine Step 2 and 3 to conclude that $$\limsup_{k \to \infty} \mathbb{P} \left( \bigcup_{n \geq k} E_n \right) \leq \limsup_{k \to \infty} \sum_{n \geq k} \mathbb{P}(E_n \cap E_{n+1}^c)=0$$ which gives $$\mathbb{P}\left( \limsup_{n \to \infty} E_n \right)=0.$$

Comment: This is great! Steps 2-4 of this I completely understand. However, I am having trouble understanding why step 1 holds (and I think this is the root of my understanding as a whole, as step 1 is what gets around the problem of breaking up the union). In particular, why do you need the $\cup_{n \geq k}(E_n \cap E_{n+1})$ in step 1? Would it be valid to say $\lim_{k \nearrow \infty} \cup_{n \geq k} E_n = \lim_{k \nearrow \infty} \cup_{N \geq k} \cap_{n \geq N} E_n$?

Comment: @user601184 No, it's not. Consider for instance $E_n := \{(-1)^n\}$ ...then $-1 \in E_n$ for infinitely many $n \in \mathbb{N}$, but $-1 \notin \bigcap_{n \geq k} E_n$ for any $k$.

Comment: I see. I think I was wrongly assuming that the $E_n$ sequence was monotone when I thought about the above statement. Returning to my original question though, can you provide any intuition/resources for breaking down the first step?

Comment: @user601184 Well, if $\omega \in \bigcup_{n \geq k} E_n$, then there exists $n \geq k$ such that $\omega \in E_n$. Now set $$M := \inf\{j \geq n+1; \omega \notin E_j\} \qquad (\inf \emptyset := \infty).$$ If $M<\infty$, then $\omega \in E_{M-1}$, $\omega \notin E_M$, and therefore the 2nd condition from step 1 is satisfied. If $M=\infty$ then $\omega \in E_j$ for all $j \geq n$, and therefore the 1st condition holds.